# List where only some columns are confidential

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, security, external-list

I have created an external list which is drawing data from a single table in an  Azure SQL Database (SAAS). Two external content type operations: List & Read Item.

This is a generic list containing information for all employees in the company such as name, position, work location, etc.  This list is used in a couple of ways :
1. To allow users to search employees for use in forms, workflow etc (cant use user profile service as not all employees are online)
2. To act as the source for an off the shelf SharePoint App that displays the org charts

Currently all data in this list is public, so confidentiality is not an issue. We have just had a request from HR to include some additional data that is confidential (such as date of birth).

Before I proceed, any advice on securing just the confidential columns? My current thoughts are to have two separate lists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So found an option.
In SP Designer, navigate to External Content Types for this connection.

On the return parameter configuration page, you can deselect individual db fields/columns.

These are then suppressed when a user views that external list. I think I will have two external lists pointing to the same source.  One list with the fields hidden (with the applicable list permissions in SP online) and another list, with all fields, restricted to the HR Group in SP online.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

you need to use third party products to achieve this functionality. permissions based on items is the only feature available. we cant restrict columns base don permissions.